# Does the Erlang plug in for IntelliJ support rebar3?

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

It supports rebar but I'm not sure if it supports rebar3 yet. Does it support rebar3 or just rebar?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. Although, the work is in progress: https://github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang/issues/704

Comment: And please everybody who would like rebar3 support, consider leaving a donation on bountysource. The issue 704 linked here has also a link to the bountysource page :-)

Comment: I'd also suggest to consider of using mad (https://github.com/synrc/mad) - it is compatible with rebar, and has interesting features (like auto-recompile and hot code reload).